# Javascript call the base class constructor

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

`Person` is base class and `Emp` inherits from `Person`. I am trying to use `name`, `location` properties of `Person` in `Emp`.

```
function Person(name, location){
   this.name = name;
   this.location = location;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function(){
   return 'Name: ' + this.name;
}

function Emp(id, name, location){
     this.id = id;
     Person.call(this, name);
     Person.call(this, location);
}

Emp.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

var e1 = new Emp(1, 'John', 'London');
e1.id   // 1
e1.name // 'London'
e1.location //undefined
```

What is causing this error and why is name taking value of London?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you calling the constructor twice with a single argument?

```
function Emp(id, name, location){
     this.id = id;
     Person.call(this, name, location);
}
```